# If a number of test cases isn't provided, when should my program stop reading input?

Tags: c++

I'm stuck at this problem where I have to run some tests and output the result. It's nothing special but the problem is it says "several test cases".

I mean it doesn't take any variable to fix the number of test cases. I wrote the code for one case and can run it a fixed amount of time with a loop. But how do I know when to stop the code when i don't know how many test cases the online judge is going to run?

Comment: When input is *closed* ?

Comment: `while(cin >> input)` or `input = bad; cin >> input; if(input == bad) exit(0);` **may** help.

Answer (score 4):

There must be some input that starts a set of input. For example an array length/ number of elements or a string. On that thing you have to keep an eye. Just keep a loop like this..

```
int n;
while(cin>>n)
{
  //do something
}
```

If nothing is mentioned you need not consider this. 
In competitive programming in general the number of test cases are mentioned..so then you can just loop over a variable considering the testcase numbers.

---

***Another way to specify end of inputs***

There is another way of specifying end of input (Often encountered in **UVA online judge** ) that is in the last line they give `-1` or a string `"END"`. So in those cases you may take values into variables after completing a test case and check whether `-1` or `"END"` is encountered and exit as required.

---

***Example***
For example: [this problem](http://codeforces.com/contest/256/problem/A) [From ***Codeforces***] specifies no test cases. Here it is expected that you just get `n` and the elements and process it and give output. Nothing else. You don't have to consider the testcases as it is not mentioned.Your program will be run multiple times on different input sets.

Comment: @Tahsin Abir.: If this answer was helpful please upvote/accept the answer.As that is what makes this post useful for future users